Find out if Spring-Boot Thead-queue is in use?
I use Spring Boot 3 and have several @Async tasks.
How can I find out if there are tasks in the queue waiting for execution?
I can configure the thead-scheduling by application.properties
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size = 30
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size = 60
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity = 100
spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive = 10s

as well as per Bean.
But did not find out how to monitor my settings to adapt it if necessarry.

Maybe with Spring Actuator https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

You can get stats on the queues for the thread pool associated with respective  ThreadPoolTaskExecutors you are using for the @Async tasks, using the executor itself. E.g.:
@Qualifier("appTaskExecutor")
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

public void invokeProcess(...) {
    log.debug("taskexec stats: " + threadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor());

